# Changing the author name In already built plugin in octobercms

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am building plugins that do simple CRUD in octobercms but the url in the backend has author name in it. I want to change it to something reliable to the website like `max/home/home` to `page/home/home`

Comment: I suggest create new plugin with correct author name and plugin name and migrate you code to it. In general you need to change name-spaces for each file and folder name accordingly. so better to create new plugin and migrate code to it, in this way its easy, safe without errors and change will refract to every thing also for table names etc ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for use `max/home/home` and replace with `page/home/home` inside model and controllers.
2. Rename the plugin folder with new author name.
3. You dont need to rebuild new tables, just make sure the models have proper table name.
4. On your theme, don't use builder to query results. Use the Models as done in laravel eloquent.